# How to fix route problem with action methods Async suffix

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have async action method named IndexAsync.

```
        [HttpGet("Index")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync([ModelBinder(typeof(ListCoursesRequestModelBinder))]ListCoursesRequestModel request)
        {
            var model = await _courseService.GetListViewModelAsync(request);

            return View(model);
        }
```

My Course controller below

```
[Route("Course")]
    public sealed class CourseController : Controller
    {
```

I'm trying /Course/Index or /Course but it returns to me NotFound page.

Controller route should be /Course or /Course/Index but I couldn't do it.

Comment: What does your RouteConfig look like?

Comment: ```app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });```